# Turing Machine Assistance

Tags: computer-science, finite-automata, automata

I've been practicing with designing Turing machines, and one that I recently solved was for a language L = { w : n<sub>a</sub>(w) = n<sub>b</sub>(w)}, where the number of a's in w are equal to the number of b's in w.

However, how would I go about designing a Turing machine for a language where the number of a's in w does not equal the number of b's in w? (eg. L = {w : n<sub>a</sub>(w) ≠ n<sub>b</sub>(w)}?

The book and websites that I've been using for reference define a Turing machine as follows:

M = (Q, Σ, ℾ, δ, q<sub>0</sub>, ☐, F), where Q is the states, Σ is the input alphabet, ℾ is the tape alphabet, δ is the transitions, q<sub>0</sub> is the start state, ☐ is a blank space that is an element of ℾ (☐ ∊ ℾ), and F is the final state designated as q<sub>f</sub>.

Comment: Stupid (but easy) solution: scan the input as usual, for each *a*, cross it, then look for a *b*. If you can't find it, accept, if you can, cross it (With a different symbol) and go back to the last *a* crossed. Do the specular with *b*s. Repeat until the end of input. Another cumbersome solution: keep a counter for the *a*s on the left of the input, one for the *b*s on the right. Count and then compare. CS theoretical solution: Let M be the TM that decides L (it exists as you proved), simulate M and accept iif M rejects (i.e. TM decidability is closed under complement).

Comment: @MargaretBloom Could you explain what you mean by "do the specular with _bs_? I don't believe I'm run across the term when used in the way you've done.

Comment: Swap the roles of *a* and *b*. When you see a *b* look for an *a*.

Comment: @MargaretBloom ok, so if I were to write the transitions would it be safe to  assume they look as below?

δ(q0, a) = (q1, x, R)

δ(q0, b) = (q, y, L)

δ(q1, a) = (q0, x, R)

δ(q1, b) = (q2, y, L)

δ(q2, ☐) = (qf, ☐, R)

Answer (score 0):

If you've recently solved the case where the number of a and b are equal, an immediate solution for the case where they're not equal is this:

- if you used to crash (have no valid transition) then add a transition to halt_accept instead;
- if you used to explicitly reject by going to halt_reject, go to halt_accept instead;
- if you used to accept by entering halt_accept, go to halt_reject instead.

This new TM (1) accepts anything that would not have been accepted by your TM for the case of equal numbers of a and b, and (2) rejects anything that would have been accepted by your TM for the case of equal numbers of a and b.

In fact, this procedure works for any TM whose job is simply to decided membership of the input string in the language of the machine; it would not work to enumerate strings in the complementary language, but that's not necessarily something you need (and you could get enumeration by using a machine constructed like this as a sub-machine in another that enumerates all strings and checks them).